# vertically and horizontally center text in image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on some css and trying to center text inside an image like this

[image]

what i have right now works *most* of the time, but there are letter combinations that make it have an off centered look (like 2 I's). right now the html/css is pretty straight forward (it should be noted, this is inside of a bootstrap navbar)

**html**

```
<a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <!-- the image (white background, blue circle) -->
  <img alt="Navbar-circle" src="/images/navbar-circle.png?1511208668" />
  <!-- the text to be centered -->
  <span class="circle-name">GK</span>
  <span class="caret dropdown-caret pull-right"></span>
</a>
```

**css**

```
image {
  height: 55px;
  width: 60px;
}

span.circle-name {
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-left: -48px;
}
```

An example of letters that work, would be like above, the combo **GK** works. For an example of 2 letters that do *not work* are **II** (which is 2 i's)

like it was mentioned, this works *ok* and for a lot of letter combinations it's just fine. but there are letter combinations where it does not. Any advice for how to get this to always be centered no matter what letters there are would be very much appreciated

Comment: Can you please add: A) A letter combination where it works, B) A letter combination where it does not work, and C) the *raw* HTML output of `<%= image_tag('navbar-circle.png')%>`, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @ObsidianAge already did

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using negative margin on your `span` I would suggest using `text-align: center;` and giving it the width of your image

There's a few ways you can achieve what you are trying to do:

1. Image as background in CSS eg. http://jsbin.com/zuvifanohi/edit?html,css,output
2. Using `flexbox` + `justify-content: center;` on your anchor container and absolutely positioning your image

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try to position it absolutely, you would need a wrapper with position relative. You could use the a tag. Adjust the margins to center the letters. -10px is half of the span height. -13px is half of the span width. You could do the same with the caret.

```css
a.dropdown-toggle  {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 55px;
  width: 60px;
  position:relative;
  padding:0;
}
img {width:100%;height:auto;}
span.circle-name {
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -13px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <!-- the image (white background, blue circle) -->
  <img alt="Navbar-circle" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Enneagram_circle.png" />
  <!-- the text to be centered -->
  <span class="circle-name">GK</span>
  <span class="caret dropdown-caret pull-right"></span>
</a>
```